# Waiting for a daemontools service to stop

Tags: linux, scripting, daemontools

I'm running a service under [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) that take several seconds to stop when sent the TERM signal. I need to stop it in a script, and then wait for the process to stop before continuing to take a LVM snapshot or restarting the service.

Does daemontools provide a way to do this? If not, what's the best way? I was thinking of sleeping while svcok exits with 0, but it seems like this should be a common problem with an easier solution. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

A way to do that I already used is to take the problem differently, in your run script you can do anything you want before running your application so you could do this:

```
#!/bin/sh

# backup anything you want
rsync xxxx

exec /path/to/app
```

and then:

```
svc -du /path/to/service
```

would stop the application and when stopped, take your backup and then restart it.

While it is not completely what you asked it serves the same goal and works well :)